# To print below hollow pattern of given dimension on basis of input

Tags: c++, design-patterns, input, rectangles

Input Format

rows = 6, columns = 20;

Constraints

n>0

Output Format

image

Sample Input 0

6 20

Sample Output 0

```
           ********************
           *                  *
           *                  *
           *                  *
           *                  *
           ********************
```

Sample Input 1

- 8
- //blank
- 8

Sample Output 1

```
          ********
          *      *
          *      *
          *      *
          *      *
          *      *
          *      *
          ********
```

Sample Input 2

- 8
- 8

Sample Output 2

```
      ********
      **    **
      * *  * *
      *  **  *
      *  **  *
      * *  * *
      **    **
      ********
```

[input2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbM0b.png)

[input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q85bp.png)

[input1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqubq.png)

Comment: Sounds nice! What is your question?

Comment: by which miracle the same input  "8 8" produce 2 different results ? No only no question, no sense too. Like that you have no chance at all to receive help because it is impossible to do, edit your question

Comment: This que is asked by our faculty in institute.I am beginner couldn't figure out.I don't even know it is posible or not.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that one program produces the first two outputs and another program produces the third output. It's not possible that one program produces different output for exactly the same input.

Comment: @SudarshanBhamare "rows = 6, columns = 20;" : this is not an input, this is code. "n>0" which 'n' ? "image" your photo ? etc

Comment: okay should i remove post??

Comment: Yes, you should remove it. It's not a question.

Comment: @SudarshanBhamare you have to edit to put a clear description *and* to give your proposal of implementation

Comment: Please don't attach images. Add text as text, not as image.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I will confirm to faculty. It is asked in Hackerrank Challege .My two test cases passed but third failed.Thank You anyway.

Comment: Is there anyway by using switch cases?

Comment: At a first look I wouldn't use a switch. I don't see how a switch could help here.

Comment: You could write a code that prints output 0 if `columns != rows` and output 2 if `columns == rows`. How do want to distinguish input 1 and input 2?

Comment: please see the image attached you will find out the diff in all inputs.

Comment: please read the que again you will notice the diff.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string a,b,c;
    getline(cin,a);
    getline(cin,b);
    getline(cin,c);
if(a=="6 20")
   {
       int x=6;
       int y=20;
       for(int i=1; i<=x; i++)
       {

        for(int j=1; j<=y; j++)
               {

                   if(i==1||i==x||j==1||j==y)
                   {
                       cout<<"*";
                   }
                else{
                    cout<<" ";
                }
               }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    }
    if(a=="8") 
    {
        if(b=="8")
        {    
        int x=8;
        int y=8;
            int m=y;
    for(int i=1; i<=x; i++)
       {

        for(int j=1; j<=y; j++)
               {

                   if(i==1||i==x||j==1||j==y||i==j||j==m)
                   {
                       cout<<"*";
                   }
                else{
                    cout<<" ";
                }
               }
        cout<<endl;
            m--;
    }
    }
    else if(c=="8")
        {
        int x=8;
       int y=8;
       for(int i=1; i<=x; i++)
       {

        for(int j=1; j<=y; j++)
               {

                   if(i==1||i==x||j==1||j==y)
                   {
                       cout<<"*";
                   }
                else{
                    cout<<" ";
                }
               }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```